Monitor the maximum memory used by Virtuoso when answering queries
I'm using Virtuoso Open-source as the DBMS of my data mining algorithm.
I need to monitor the maximum memory used by Virtuoso when answering queries sent by my data mining process.
I noticed that when Virtuoso starts, the DBMS acquires a lot of memory in advance according to the configuration settings in virtuoso.ini.
This is certainly not the actual memory used by answering my data queries.
For example, Virtuoso acquires 50GB memory when it starts, but throughout my data mining process, only maximum 5GB is actually used to answer the data queries.
I would like to get the number 5GB (the peak memory usage) instead of 50GB.
Is it possible to monitor such peak memory usage by Virtuoso?

This is a fairly deep under-the-covers, product-specific question, and would be much better raised on the Virtuoso Open Source project on GitHub, or on the OpenLink Community Forum.
